# .htaccess switch between mobile en desktop view?

Tags: .htaccess, mobile, redirect, url-rewriting

I have the following htaccess file. This will redirect users to m.website.com when a mobile device is detected. This works, however, when people visit the mobile website on m.website.com they have the option to switch to desktop view (if they prefer). When they clicked on desktop view they will be send to www.website.com (which at this point sends them back to m.website.com) but in this situation I like to keep them at the original website at www.website.com. Is there a way with the COOKIE that if a certain condition is met, they will be kept on the desktop website and if that condition is not met the redirect will occur?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)m=0(&|$)
RewriteRule ^ - [CO=mredir:0:www.website.com]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:x-wap-profile} !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Profile}       !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "acs|alav|alca|amoi|audi|aste|avan|benq|bird|blac|blaz|brew|cell|cldc|cmd-" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "dang|doco|eric|hipt|inno|ipaq|java|jigs|kddi|keji|leno|lg-c|lg-d|lg-g|lge-" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  "maui|maxo|midp|mits|mmef|mobi|mot-|moto|mwbp|nec-|newt|noki|opwv" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "palm|pana|pant|pdxg|phil|play|pluc|port|prox|qtek|qwap|sage|sams|sany" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "sch-|sec-|send|seri|sgh-|shar|sie-|siem|smal|smar|sony|sph-|symb|t-mo" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "teli|tim-|tosh|tsm-|upg1|upsi|vk-v|voda|w3cs|wap-|wapa|wapi" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "wapp|wapr|webc|winw|winw|xda|xda-" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "up.browser|up.link|windowssce|iemobile|mini|mmp" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "symbian|midp|wap|phone|pocket|mobile|pda|psp" [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !macintosh [NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}          !^m\.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)m=0(&|$) 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE}        !^.*mredir=0.*$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^ http://m.website.com [R,L]
```

Comment: It appears that you are already doing that i.e. setting a cookie if `m=0` is present as a query string and *not redirecting* to mobile site if this cookies is present.

Comment: hmm I am going to investigate that...

Comment: you are correct ?m=0 will indeed stop it from redirecting... now I am investigating how to get the effect back to mobile :)